# How can I add files programmatically to a visual studio template?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I have created a visual studio project template for .net core applications. When creating a new project using this template I want to have the ability to select between Azure Authentication and Identity Authentication. In order to achieve this, I have created a wizard. Depending on the selected option on the wizard, some additional files must be included in the project. My problem is that I have no clue about how can I add those extra files to my project.

**1st Approach**

At first I created an Item Template and tried to add its contents to my project.

**AzureAuthentication.vstemplate**

```
<VSTemplate>
    <TemplateData>
        <!-- code removed for clarity -->
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <Folder Name="Models" TargetFolderName="Models">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="RefreshTokenResponse.cs">RefreshTokenResponse.cs</ProjectItem>
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="Controllers" TargetFolderName="Controllers">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="UserController.cs">UserController.cs</ProjectItem>
        </Folder>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

**WizardImplementation.cs**

```
public class WizardImplementation : IWizard {
    public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams) {
        dte = automationObject as DTE;

        // code removed for clarity
    }

    public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project) {
        switch (authenticationType) {
            default: break;
            case AuthenticationType.Azure: {
                    // code removed for clarity

                    using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:/Users/pasjiannis.OFFICE/Desktop/log.txt")) {
                        dte.Solution.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, projectPath, "AzureAuthentication");
                    }

                    break;
                }
            case AuthenticationType.Identity: {
                    break;
                }
        }
}
```

This approach doesn't work at all.

**2nd Approach**

Then I converted my template from Item Template to Project Template.

**AzureAuthentication.vstemplate**

```
<VSTemplate>
    <TemplateData>
        <!-- code removed for clarity -->
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <Project File="AzureAuthentication.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
            <Folder Name="Models" TargetFolderName="Models">
                <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="RefreshTokenResponse.cs">RefreshTokenResponse.cs</ProjectItem>
            </Folder>
            <Folder Name="Controllers" TargetFolderName="Controllers">
                <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="UserController.cs">UserController.cs</ProjectItem>
            </Folder>
        </Project>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

This worked partially. The files were added to my project successfully, but another project was also created to my solution.

**3rd Approach**

Instead of using the AddFromTemplate method in my WizardImplementation class,  I tried to access my project, get the its project items and add the new items there like this

```
dte.Solution.Projects.Items(0).ProjectItems.AddFromFile("UserController.cs");
```

But ProjectItems on my Project is null.

What am I missing here? Is any of my approaches correct or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using my 3rd approach. I was missing the fact that `dte.Solution.Projects.Items(0)` was giving me the folder that contained my project, not the project itself.

All I had to do is to change:

`dte.Solution.Projects.Items(0).ProjectItems.AddFromFile("UserController.cs");`

to

`dte.Solution.Projects.Items(0).SubProject.ProjectItems.AddFromFile("UserController.cs");`

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with this requirement, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220136/how-to-add-conditions-in-visual-studio-template-schema-and-generate-projects-bas

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. This is an old post and I haven't done any related work since then